# How to make a stream query with something like a timer?

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I'm making a siddhi app. What I need is a query to get an event from a stream if no event with the same ID arrives in certain time.

This is for a SiddhiApp with WSO2 stream processor.

lets say a json arrives at time 0s

{
  "id": "1566",
  "state":"Cochabamba"
}

then another at time 1s with different ID

{
  "id": "1575",
  "Departamento":"La Paz"
}

and another at time 4s

{
  "id": "1575",
  "Departamento":"La Paz"
}

What the query should do is to out just the first 1

{
  "id": "1566",
  "state":"Cochabamba"
}

Because it match the condition. Just one event in 5 seconds. 
The other 1575 has two events in that time.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way with detecting non ocurring events

https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/#detecting-non-occurring-events

```
from every( s1 = SweetProductionStream) -> not SweetProductionStream[s1.id == id ] for 8 seconds
select s1.resource1 as resource
insert  into resource1;
```

this code says that on a reaching event it will wait if an event with same id does not reach the stream for 8 seconds then it will insert into resource1 stream